# Angular constant as method parameter in html

Tags: angularjs, constants

I have defined the following constants in my app module

```
angular.module("Test", [])
  .constants("CONST", {
       CONSTANT: "myConstant"
})
.controller("TestCtrl" ['CONST', function(const){
$scope.testConst = function(myConst){
   if(myConst == CONST.CONSTANT){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
 } 
}]);
```

In my html code i have

```
<p ng-if="testConst(CONST.CONSTANT)"/>
```

When i debug my method i see that myConst variable is undefined. How can i pass the constant variable as parameter in the Html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add it to the scope. As constants aren't available to the dom.

```
.controller("TestCtrl" ['CONST', function(CONST){
    $scope.CONST = CONST;
    $scope.testConst = function(myConst){
       if(myConst == CONST.CONSTANT){
          return true;
       }else{
          return false;
       }
     } 
}]);
```

Comment: `if(myConst == CONST.CONSTANT){` should be `if(myConst == const.CONSTANT){`

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just copied his code, didn't realize it had errors.